# Setting my ISP's modem to let me call via my landline when I'm not home, using its internal hidden SIP server

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, sip

My ISP offers to his VDSL users the ability to use any smartphone as a cordless home phone, using an official app.

They provide no documentation or source code, but someone managed to de-obfuscate the app and found out that it works thanks to a SIP server that runs on the modem/router the ISP lends to their customers. There is no way to configure it, it's completely hidden to the average user.

This guy also found the way the app obtains the credentials needed for the login, thus enabling any device with a SIP client installed on it to connect to the router and receive and make calls on the land line.

The address the app uses for the login is a string (`modemtelecom.homenet.telecomitalia.it`) that is resolved to the router's LAN address (by default `192.168.1.1`). If I try to login to `user@192.168.1.1` it works fine; anyway, if I attempt to log in to the server, using as host address my external IP address, it fails.

I tried to set the router to forward traffic incoming from the WAN on the SIP port to its own address, but it refuses to do so (I don't know if this may be a restriction from the ISP or something one just can't do).

Do you think there may be a way to trick my router into letting me login to the SIP server while I'm outside my home LAN?

---

As *MariusMatutiae* suggested me, I set up a OpenVPN server on a PC connected to my LAN; I then proceeded to masquerade the traffic from OpenVPN, and successfully connected my Android smartphone to the VPN and the SIP server inside my LAN. So far though it seems like I can only *send* audio, without being able to receive anything.

Anyways, this looks like the right track: to try to get help with the issues I encountered, I asked another question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1159310).

Comment: Your routing table is very different from that of my routed OpenVPNs: how do you set it up?  Can you add the output of *ip link show dev tun0*? Did you install the package *bridge-utils*? You should have: do it, then reboot the computer and try again. Your thoughts are correct, but on an OpenVPN what you say should be done automatically.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae thanks for the suggestions. I updated the OP; I didn't have bridge-utils installed, so I did as you suggested but nothing has changed unfortunately.

Comment: has your routing table changed?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm afraid not. May I ask you what should it look like?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae maybe it would be the case for me to open a new question? The title has become a bit outdated given the progress I made thanks to you: theoretically we have a solution, now the problem is how to get OpenVPN to work properly.

Comment: For the routing table pls see my Edit. You are welcome to ask a different question. Tu studi all'estero, Lorenzo?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I moved part of the content I added the last time to my OP into a new question, since the topic had been drastically changed. I want to thank you one more time for the insights you gave me. _By the way, I'm not studying abroad, what made you think so?_ :)

Comment: The times when you connect. But then I must be wrong, I often am.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm having an intense week, so I can only connect when here is early in the morning or late night. That must have misled you, but that's no problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I try to login to user@192.168.1.1 it works fine; anyway, if I attempt to log in to the server, using as host address my external IP address, it fails.

Of course it fails: if it didn't, I (and many, many other people ;-) ) would be making calls thru your SIP server, at your expense.

The way to make it work is to make sure your phone, when outside your home, has an IP address within your LAN. This can be achieved if you set up a [routed OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) server on a Linux box at home (it can be done with a Raspberry pi 3, a small pc which costs little more than 40 euros).

There is an OpenVPN app for Android and iOS (and perhaps some other OS but I am not sure, you will have to check), which allows phones to use *routed* OpenVPNs (**not** bridged OpenVPNs, careful). The only missing ingredient is the use of a *MASQUERADE* rule on the Linux box,

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 ! -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

(if you are using the subnet *10.0.0.0/24* for your OpenVPN clients, otherwise change accordingly). At this point, all traffic from your phone directed to your LAN, including the SIP server, will appear as coming from the Linux box, which **does** have an IP address in your LAN, and thus your phone will be able to access your SIP server.

This **will** work, but possibly in a sub-ideal way. If sound quality is not ideal, if there is stuttering or intermittent connections, you will have to learn how to prioritize VoIP traffic on your LAN. But since this already is setup thru your ISP modem, my bet is it will work out of the box.

It is a tad complex, but lots of fun. All steps are well documented on a gazillion sites, just use your Google.

**EDIT**

Your routing table should look like this:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0
10.8.73.128/26 via 10.8.73.130 dev tun0 
10.8.73.130 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.73.129 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.128 
192.168.73.0/24 dev brlan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.73.1
```

My Debian router has two interfaces, *eth0* is the WAN and *brlan* is the LAN. 192.168.73.0/24 is the LAN, 192.168.1.0/254 in the WAN-side connection to my modem, 10.8.73.128/26 is the OpenVPN net, and what you are missing is the important statement

```
10.8.73.130 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.73.129
```

which defines the tunnel.

Comment: Android has PPTP VPNs as a supported option, many routers have that stock. Depending on OP's system. this might be a 'neater' option. Also worth considering he may have a non static IP address, which makes things more fun.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm currently trying to set up OpenVPN, as soon as I manage to get it to work I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok, I set up everything on a pc connected to the LAN and on my cellphone. After a bit of work I managed to login and make calls but I can't listen anything, only the number I call can receive the sound.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be the fault? (would have edited my last comment but I don't have enough privileges)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Alright, I recorded both `eth0` and `tun0` from the moment the smartphone connected to OpenVPN; I then logged in to the SIP server, made a call to a house phone, and disconnected after a few seconds.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae The output is very long, maybe it would be more appropriate to ask a new question? Or should I post it on pastebin?

(sorry to make yet another duplicate comment, I'm used to enter a new line upon finishing talking about a concept but I can't remember that when commenting it will directly send the message)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae pastebin.com/RpJD9d53 (`eth0`) and pastebin.com/ydfWBAJe (`tun0`); I've begun calling at 22:23:02, and accepted the call on the PC at 22:23:09. No audio could be heard on the cellphone.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae it's me who should be thanking you :) actually, I did figure out that the `iptables` command wasn't working, so I googled and found this one: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`, which gives me the same result as the one you updated, unfortunately. So still no audio incoming. I was wondering though, is there a way to assign the cellphone his own local IP as if it was physically connected to the LAN, using OpenVPN? I can't see how packages incoming from 192.168.1.1 and heading to the OpenVPN machine should know they have to go to my cellphone.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae thank you, I have added to the OP the output and a few thoughts I had.