# OpenVPN server not working as it should: can't receive most packets from LAN device to tunneled client

Tags: networking, router, openvpn

In order to login from the internet to a SIP server running on my home router (`192.168.1.1`), that for several reasons is only reachable from within my LAN, [it was suggested to me](https://superuser.com/questions/1158040/setting-my-isps-modem-to-let-me-call-via-my-landline-when-im-not-home-using-i?noredirect=1#comment1669297_1158040) to set up a routed OpenVPN server.

In this way I could theoretically trick my router into thinking that the traffic incoming from a remote device, namely my cellphone via an Android client app, came from my own OpenVPN server. Since the server would be running on a PC connected to my LAN (in my case, `192.168.1.3`), this could effectively enable me to login to the SIP server from my cellphone.

I installed OpenVPN on a Linux Mint (Ubuntu) desktop PC:

```
$ uname -a
Linux lorenzo-desktop 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and following both the official how-to and some information I found elsewhere, I came up with this `server.conf` file (only the relevant bits are shown):

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
persist-key
persist-tun
topology subnet
```

I was advised from another user ([MariusMatutiae](https://superuser.com/users/255732/mariusmatutiae)) to add the following *iptables* rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

I have also enabled IP forwarding on the PC hosting the server and correctly set port forwarding on my home router. After doing so the server should work correctly, but instead this is what happens:

- I can login to the OpenVPN server running on `192.168.1.3`, which assigns my remote client the IP `10.8.0.6`;
- I can ping any device on my LAN, among which my modem/router on `192.168.1.1` running the SIP server;
- I can successfully login to the SIP server (so I imagine there must be some kind of handshake between my cellphone and the router);
- I can call other devices connected to the SIP server from the cellphone, and they can hear me, but **I can't hear the audio that should be coming from them**.

This is the output from `ip route show`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.3  metric 1
```

and from `ip link show dev tun0`:

```
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 100
    link/none
```

Finally, here you can find the outputs from [`tcpdump -i eth0`](http://pastebin.com/RpJD9d53) and from [`tcpdump -i tun0`](http://pastebin.com/ydfWBAJe).

My question: **can anyone guess what could be wrong?** Missing packages? Incorrect server configuration? Missing *iptables* entries?

**EDIT #1:**

Unfortunately I can't add routes to my router; if it may be useful, its model name is Technicolor AG Plus. It doesn't have much room for hacking, you know, I'm lucky it supports DDNS.

This is the only active *iptables* rule on the PC hosting the OpenVPN server:

```
# iptables -vL -t nat
[...]
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 25 packets, 1672 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   61  3949 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    anywhere            !10.8.0.0/24
```

**Network configuration recap**

- **[`192.168.1.1`]** is the modem/router provided by my ISP that I use to connect to the internet; it's a quite rudimentary device, it has no mean to set routes, and has no VPN capability. It runs the **SIP server** I want to connect to.
- **[`192.168.1.2`]** is a router that I use as a network extender. It is set in such a way that it is completely transparent to the traffic passing through it. So far I had no problem with it and I really don't think it has any influence on my issue. Many SIP clients connect through it and can successfully make and receive calls.
- **[`192.168.1.3`]** is a PC running Linux Mint, connected via Ethernet cable to `192.168.1.2`, that runs the **OpenVPN server**. In the VPN, its address is **[`10.8.0.1`]**. My home router (`192.168.1.1`) forwards incoming traffic on port 1194 to this device.
- **My smartphone** connects to the internet using the 3G cellular network. It can connect to the OpenVPN server and obtain an address such as **[`10.8.0.6`]**. It can login to the SIP server running on `192.168.1.1` but I have one-way audio, from the smartphone to the target SIP device.

Comment: Can you add a route to your router? If so, try adding: *ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.3* (I assume 192.168.1.3 is the IP address of the OpenVPN server). Also, what is your firewall configuration on the OpenVPN server?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae thanks for the suggestion, I updated the OP. May I ask you what do you think about my server's configuration file? I assembled it by trial and error, referring to many sources.

Comment: Can you say what your box is? *uname -a*?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae sure, I'm running Linux Mint. I have to say that I also tried to set everything up on my Arch laptop, but for reasons unknown to me it didn't make me ping my router even with the exact same configuration that I tried on my desktop PC. (of course I edited the port forwarding accordingly)

Comment: You now have a “SIP client behind NAT” situation, which will probably require port forwards *on your VPN server*.

Comment: @DanielB I have made some research about that, but I couldn't understand well what you suggest. Do I have to tweak the VPN server's configuration file or the PC's iptables? And above all, in what way? Unfortunately I'm not very experienced and I can't figure this out by myself. For clarity I tried to make a summary of my network topology at the end of my OP.

Comment: Port forwarding is done via IPTables. However, it’s unlikely you’ll ever get this to work reliably. [This article](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/NAT+and+VOIP) offers a pretty good summary. It’ll be a lot easier to just bridge the VPN network.